# How to generate active_admin:install on active admin rails 5 primary support?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

Activeadmin [readme](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) suggests to use following to use for primary support on rails 5.

```
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources
```

Even after `$ bundle install` it says there is no `active_admin:install` generator available.

```
$ rails generate active_admin:install
Running via Spring preloader in process 6209
Could not find generator 'active_admin:install'. Maybe you meant 'responders:install', 'active_record:model' or 'active_record:migration'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Active Admin master has preliminary support for Rails 5. To give it a
>   try, these Gemfile changes **may be needed**.

Whats mean you should add this gem with `gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'`, so Gemfile should looks like:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'activeadmin/inherited_resources
```

Read the readme carefully.

Comment: Run "bundle pack" and "bundle install --path vendor/cache" command if you are having "git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git (at master) is not yet checked out. Run 'bundle install' first." message.